# Android studio ошибка модуля и превью

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle

Я только что скачал андроид студию, синхронизировал его с проектом из github desktop

1. Почему выдает так много ошибок красным?
2. Проблема с превью дизайна, делаю синхорнизацию gradle  и выдает новую ошибку
3. Почему у меня не отображает модуль?

Я прошуршал весь интернет уже на протяжении 5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скачал branch с GitHub и запустил как уже существующий проет в андроид студио, теперь выдает такиую ошибку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наведите курсор мыши на то, что светится красным, посмотрите, какую ошибку пишет. И попробуйте `File` -> `Invalidate Cashes / Restart...`.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov пробовал перед переустановкой, не помогало, сейчас попробую и отпишусь)

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov без результатов, все то же самое(
по поводу ошибок, я не понимаю почему, потому что это груповой проект и на устроиствах моих коллег эти ошибки не выступают. Вот к примеру у меня:
Attribute android:background is not allowed here
Element LinearLayout is not allowed here

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос build.gradle файл проблемного модуля

Comment: больше чем уверен что в логах gradle светится ошибка SDK, но здесь вместо логов как обычно показаны ошибки совершенно другие

Comment: Лучше делать импорт проекта

Comment: Простите, как это сделать?

Comment: Запустил проект через импорт, и попробовал открыть как уже готовый проект, обновил в вопросе. Теперь новая ошибка: 09:43 Project Sync
   The project 'COMP2003-2020-M-MobileInterfaceDevelopment' is not a Gradle-based project